# CSS calculation decimal point accuracy problem?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
    *{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
    .box{display:flex;width:600px;height:300px;}
    .left{
        flex-grow: 0.991;
        width: 100px;
        background: green;
    }
</style>

<div class='box'>
    <div class="left" id="left"></div>
    <script>
        console.log(document.getElementById('left').getBoundingClientRect().width);// 595.4874877929688
    </script>
</div>
```

I expect the width of the element  to be `100+(500*0.991)=595.5` 
And the chrome devtools Elements option show  `549.49` why not `595.5`?

Answer (score -1):

I copied your code and tested it on chrome and firefox and returns 595.484375 as width value. Have you tried to delete cache? or tried another browser?

Comment: This may be because the browser version is inconsistent, but this is not the point. I expect it to be 595.5。